# script to backup, compress and clear eventlogs returns negative filesize value

Tags: windows, vbscript, automation, event-log, windows-server

Here at work we have an increasing number of alerts regarding event log high usage (mostly on the security log).
To solve that we've written a script that automatically copies, compresses and clears the eventlog, and added it as a scheduled task.

So far so good and its been working great on many servers.

However, when the log maximum filesize is set to 2097152 kB or above the function returns a negative value (most likely because it goes offrange since it returns it as bytes).

The extraction of the code that is failing is as follows:

```
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate, (Backup, Security)}!\\" & strServer & "\root\cimv2")
For Each Item in oWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTEventLogFile WHERE LogFileName='Security'")
    Report = Report & vbNewLine & " " & Item.LogFileName & " log" & vbNewLine & _
             "  Maximum size: " & (Item.MaxFileSize/1024) & " KB" & vbNewLine & _
             "  Current size: " & (Item.FileSize/1024) & " KB" & vbNewLine & _
             "  Usage percentage: " & _
             Round(((Item.FileSize * 100) / Item.MaxFileSize),2) & vbewLine
```

Is there any workaround or any way to edit the code so that it supports log max file sizes of 2097152 kB and above, or is it a limitation of the `GetObject()` function?

Comment: Why are you multiplying `FileSize` by 100? My suggestion would be to save the file size in KB in a variable and then do your various calculations on that. Also the last word has a typo (vbewLine).

Comment: Its to get the usage %, anyway thats not the issue, since it works. 
Problem is that Item.FileSize is in bytes and when the eventlog is setted at 2097152 or above it gets a negative value. And thats where everything fails

Comment: So that's why you should convert to KB and do your calculations on that, as the numbers will be smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394225.aspx) the `MaxFileSize` property is an unsigned 32-bit integer value:

> **MaxFileSize**
>
> Data type: **uint32**
>   Access type: Read/write

However, VBScript doesn't recognize unsigned data types, so the value gets misinterpreted. You need to correct it yourself, e.g. like this:

```
Function FixUInt32(val)
  If val >= 0 Then
    FixUInt32 = val
  Else
    FixUInt32 = 4294967296 + val
  End If
End Function
```

Beware that, again as documented, having logs this large is possible, but not recommended:

> Although event logs can be sized as large as 4 gigabytes, in practice they should be limited to no more than 300 megabytes. Event logs larger than that can be difficult to analyze because of the number of events contained within the log and because event logs are not optimized for data retrieval.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ansgar!